# Same encode, same charset, different results

Tags: php, encode

I have two MySQL databases in different servers:

- server A (development): collation latin1_general_ci
- server B (production): collation latin1_general_ci

And I have two php servers:

- server A (development): exif.encode_unicode ISO-8859-15; default_charset UTF-8; version 7.1.22
- server B (production):  exif.encode_unicode ISO-8859-15; default_charset UTF-8; version 7.2.34

Results in server A for `utf8_encode($str)`:

```
HOSPITAL Assunção
```

Results in server B for `utf8_encode($str)`:

```
HOSPITAL AssunÃ§Ã£o
```

What am I missing? Why are they different? :-(